# windows form - pass value from child1 form to child2 form in mdi parent - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to pass value from one `child form` to another `child form` in a mdi parent vb.net

```
child 1 code -
Dim objKey As New frmKeyboard
objKey.Show()
```

opens the child 2 form

```
child 2 code - 
Dim Obj As New frmSoll
Obj.strVari = txtSearch.Text
Me.Close()
```

Comment: `txtSearch` textbox is in form1 or mdi form ah? and those two forms show form parent form ah?

Comment: txtSearch textbox in form1, yes both shows from parent

Comment: `txtSearch.Text` stored any where and you show the second form when form1 shown time ah or after form1 close show form2 ah?

Comment: when click on button in form1 form2 will show not closing form1, in form2 if i click the button form2 should close and value should pass from form2 to form1 textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

**Form 2 Button_click Event**

```
   Dim xfr As New Form3
   xfr.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
   xfr.strVari.Text =txtSearch.Text
   xfr.Show()
```

**Form3 Button Click**

```
    For Each xFrm As Form In CType(Me.MdiParent, Object).MdiChildren

                If xFrm.Name = "Form2" Then
                    CType(xFrm, Object).TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
                End If

   Next

   Me.Close()
```

Comment: Working but the form3 is showing bigger than the actual form size

Comment: which is parent form?

Comment: please wait ll convert ur code in vb.net and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Hello another possibility is to use eventhandler and and send messages or values from one child to other via it's parent or even to parent.

Here is my example in c# (sorry I understand VB.NET but don't speak. :) )

**Parent form:**

```
/// Mdi parent form
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    private int ChildCounter = 0;

    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    }

    //Child forms will hook to this event handler
    public event MessageEventHandler MessageHandler;

    /// Sends the message.
    public void SendMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageHandler != null) MessageHandler(e);
    }

    /// Adds children form.
    private void btnAddChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var child = new ChildForm(this) { Name = string.Format("child_{0}", ChildCounter++) };
        child.Text = child.Name;
        child.Show();
    }
}

/// Event handler delegate
public delegate void MessageEventHandler(MessageEventArgs e);

/// Message argument with recipient and message
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

**Child form:**

```
/// Children form
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    //Contructor which will setup child form
    public ChildForm(ParentForm parent)
        : this()
    {
        this.MdiParent = parent;
        if (parent != null)
            parent.MessageHandler += Message_Received; // Register to receive message from handler

    }
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    /// Unregister event receiver while closing form.
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = this.MdiParent as ParentForm;
        if(parent!=null)
        {
            parent.MessageHandler -= Message_Received;
        }
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }


    /// Manage received message.
    private void Message_Received(MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        // When no ricipient all child form will show message.
        if (e.Recipient == this.Name || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Recipient))
        {
            txtReceivedMessage.Text = e.Message;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }


    /// Sends message when button pressed.
    private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = MdiParent as ParentForm;
        if (this.MdiParent != null)
        {
            // MessageEventArgs contains information about recipient and message.
            parent.SendMessage(new MessageEventArgs() { Recipient = txtRecipientName.Text, Message = txtMessageToSend.Text });

        }
    }
}
```

[image]